# What is the difference between "Microsoft Office Developer Tools" and "Visual Studio Tools for Office"

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, ms-office, vsto

What is the difference between **Microsoft Office Developer Tools** and **Visual Studio Tools for Office** aka **VSTO**?

When I install the capability below, exactly which one of those two technologies am I using?

[image]

TIA.

Comment: That is an excellent question, I keep on confusing the two.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*Visual Studio Tools for Office* (or *VSTO*) is Microsoft's framework for managed add-ins in office applications, starting with Office 2003 with later versions supporting only Office 2007+.

*Apps for Office* is Microsoft's framework for HTML5 apps in office applications, starting with Office 2013.

*Office Developer Tools* are tools (usually under the form of Visual Studio project templates) to develop both *VSTO* and *Apps for Office* applications.

So when you create an "Excel 2007 Workbook" project as in your screenshot, you're using a VSTO project template installed as part of the Office Developer Tools.

Comment: So what you are saying is that *before* HTML5, the 2 were one and the same. They were inseparable.

Comment: @swiss_programmer They were inseperable I guess, but they are not the same. The VSTO project template comes with Office Developer Tools, but once deployed and installed on the client machine it's just a VSTO application.

Comment: I guess the "Office Developer Tools" could be otherwise named "VSTO Templates" or "VSTO Developer Tools" (at the time).

Answer (score 3):

I found the more detailed answer.

[What are similarities and differences between Microsoft Office Developer Tools for Visual Studio and Visual Studio Tools for Office?](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/d2945fd5-48d5-43ac-bd9c-c31d4ae1c607/what-are-similarities-and-differences-between-microsoft-office-developer-tools-for-visual-studio-and?forum=vsto)

> Some information regarding Microsoft Office Developer Tools for Visual
>   Studio
>
> Microsoft has released Office Developer Tools for Visual Studio. The
>   tools have been available in preview form, and offer an alternative to
>   Napa, Microsoft’s online lightweight app creator.
>
> The extensions to Visual Studio can be used to write apps for Office,
>   SharePoint and Office 365. Earlier versions of Office used Visual
>   Basic for Applications as the programming language. The new extensions
>   let you write apps for Office and SharePoint using web technologies
>   such as HTML5, CSS, JavaScript, REST, OData, and OAuth.
>
> Apps developed can be sold in the Office Store or used internally in
>   your own company. The new release also lets you write apps that make
>   use of SharePoint without having SharePoint on your local machine.
>
> An app for Office is basically a webpage that is hosted inside an
>   Office client application, and the apps you can write for Office and
>   SharePoint come in three categories
>
> those      that appear in the task pane of an Office application;
>   those      that appear inside the content of an Office document such
>   as a worksheet;      and mail apps for Outlook and      Outlook Web
>   Access. These appear next to an open Outlook item, such as an
>   email message, meeting request, meeting response, meeting
>   cancellation, or      appointment. The basic components of an app for
>   Office are an XML manifest file and a webpage. The manifest defines
>   various settings and points to the webpage that implements the app UI
>   and custom logic.
>
> According to the overview of the new tools, an app for Office can do
>   pretty much anything a webpage can do inside the browser, such as
>   provide an interactive UI and custom logic through JavaScript, or use
>   JavaScript frameworks such as jQuery.
>
> The second method of developing for Office 13 and 365 is to use
>   Microsoft’s “Napa” online development tool, which Microsoft describes
>   as a lightweight companion to Visual Studio. Napa is a free
>   browser-based app for SharePoint that you can use to write apps.
>
> While light-weight apps may meet some needs, it’s worth noting that
>   Visual Basic for Applications and VSTO do both still work in Office
>   2013, the only drawback is that you can’t use them to create apps that
>   can be sold in the Office Store.
>
> For many existing Office developers, the push away from the rich
>   client offered in Visual Basic for Applications is a disadvantage. The
>   benefit of being able to sell them in the Office Store is only
>   available if you have an Office 365 Developer Subscription, which
>   includes a SharePoint Online Developer Site customized for creating
>   and testing apps, and a Microsoft Seller Dashboard account to make
>   your apps in the Store.
>
> Some information regarding VSTO:-
>
> VSTO, or Visual Studio Tools for Office, or Microsoft Visual Studio
>   Tools is part of Microsoft's Visual Studio .NET tools suite and
>   supports the Microsoft .NET Framework. It is used by developers to
>   write code connecting Microsoft Office Word, Excel and Outlook
>   applications. Developers using VSTO can employ C# or Visual Basic
>   languages. It is an alternative to Visual Basic for Applications, or
>   VBA
>
> You can use the Microsoft Office developer tools in Visual Studio to
>   create .NET Framework applications that extend Office. These
>   applications are also named Office solutions.
>
> The Office developer tools provide features that help you create
>   Office solutions to suit a variety of business needs. The tools
>   include project templates to help you create Office solutions by using
>   Visual Basic or Visual C#, and visual designers that help you create
>   custom user interfaces for your Office solutions.

Answer (score -4):

**Visual Studio Tools for Office** (aka **VSTO**) is the MS Office half.

**Microsoft Office Developer Tools** is the Visual Studio half.

Comment: How is VSTO just the MS office half? They are build in Visual Studio are they not?